# Autoplay music on webpage issue

Tags: html, css

I have the following page which used to autoplay the embedded mp3 once the intro starts,
For some reason, it stopped working and I cannot figure out why. The MP3 file still works if I play it manually. I have tried numerous different ways of embedding and autoplaying the file with no luck.
If I reload the page enough times, it will randomly work occasionally.
Can anyone tell me what the problem is here.

https://michaels.me.uk/wp-content/uploads/zenith-intro/

Comment: looks fine to me. The music starts as expected

Comment: I have tested it on multiple browsers with the same issue though. Maybe you just one of the random occasions where it works.

Answer (score 0):

The browser requests a user interaction for auto play to work. So if I visit your page and click anywhere on the screen a user interaction will be registered and the audio will play automatically.

if I then refresh the page via the address bar but don't click on the screen the audio won't play and will throw the following error -

```
DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document 
first.
```

Not sure if there is a workaround for this. Let me know if you find one.

Comment: has there been a change in browser behaviour recently to cause this, as it used to work just fine.